# Python - Maximum of Array

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the maximum value of an array. I got the following index error when I ran my code.

```
if line[i] <= line[i + 1] and currentMaximum[0] <= line[i + 1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

```
with open('C:/Users/Obama/Documents/Scripts/sums.txt', 'r') as f:

    currentMaximum = []
    i = 0
    for line in f:
        line = list(map(int, line.split()))
        if line[i] <= line[i + 1] and currentMaximum[0] <= line[i + 1]:
            currentMaximum[0] = line[i + 1]
        elif line[i] >= line[i + 1] and currentMaximum[0] <= line[i]:
            currentMaximum[0] = line[i]
        else:
            continue
        i += 1
```

Comment: Could you share/paste some content from sums.txt?

Comment: You are incrementing `i` on each line of the file, but you then use this 'line number' value to index the line itself.  This is what is causing your error.  For example, if your file had 5000 lines and the last line only had three elements, you would be trying to index the 5000th value of a list with only three elements.

Comment: Why is `currentMaximum` an array? The only element you ever use is `[0]`.

Comment: You probably need a nested loop: `for num in line:` if you want to find the maximum number in `line`.

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the bugs in your code will give you something this:

```
with open('C:/Users/Obama/Documents/Scripts/sums.txt', 'r') as f:

    currentMaximum = [0]
    for line in f:
        line = list(map(int, line.split()))
        i = 0
        while i < len(line) - 1:
            if line[i] <= line[i + 1] and currentMaximum[0] <= line[i + 1]:
                currentMaximum[0] = line[i + 1]
            elif line[i] >= line[i + 1] and currentMaximum[0] <= line[i]:
                currentMaximum[0] = line[i]
            i += 1
print currentMaximum[0]
```

`currentMaximum[0]` needs to have a value when you do your first comparison, so I initialized it with 0 to begin with.  If your data might all be negative, then maybe use `float("-inf")` instead.  Also you should reset `i` for each line, and make sure `i` never gets above `len(line) - 1`.  The above code should run ok.

If you eliminate redundancies, the code will look much simpler:

```
currentMaximum = 0

with open('C:/Users/Obama/Documents/Scripts/sums.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        for number in list(map(int, line.split())):
            if currentMaximum < number:
                currentMaximum = number

print currentMaximum
```

Alternatively use the `max` built-in, combined with list comprehensions and the `chain` function in the `itertools` standard library module.

```
from itertools import chain

with open('C:/Users/Obama/Documents/Scripts/sums.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [[int(text) for text in line.split()] for line in f]
print max(chain(*data))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will find the max value of an array.  As for getting the array, I'll leave that up to you.  Note, the variable `maxi` is used because `max` is a keyword.

```
num = []
# Put your numbers in the above array
maxi = 0

for i in num:
    if i > maxi:
        maxi = i
print(maxi)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I guess I made things a lot more complicated than they needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using builtin max function?

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randn(100)
maximum = max(arr)
```

If you have several lists and you need to find maximum of the all you could use list generation:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.randn(100)
arr2d = arr.reshape(10,10)
maximum = max([max(line) for line in arr2d])
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is because you are accessing the 0th element of cutrentMaimumx. But your array is emty, i.e. length of array is 0,so it gives index out of range exception.

Answer (score -1):

if you only need the maximum value of the `line` array you can get it by using `np.amax(line)`

Examples of usage in the [python documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)